# Angular Promises undefined Error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-promise

This the first time working promises i have this function that return a promise.

```
  public DatesGenerator(futercampaign: ICampaign, searchparam: any, i: number): ng.IPromise<any> {
    return this.$q((resolve, reject) => {
      let num: number;
      let month: number;
      let tempDate: Date;
      let deadline: Date = new Date(searchparam.start_date);
      let periodicity: Date = new Date(searchparam.start_date);

      if (searchparam.periodicity === 'onemonth') { num = (i * 1); month = 1; } else if (searchparam.periodicity === 'twomonth') { num = (i * 2); month = 2; } else if (searchparam.periodicity === 'threemonth') { num = (i * 3); month = 3; }
      if (searchparam.periodicity === '14') {
        resolve(() => {
          futercampaign.start_date = new Date(periodicity.setDate(periodicity.getDate() + (searchparam.periodicity * i)));

          /* Storing the start_date temporarily */
          tempDate = new Date(futercampaign.start_date);

          /* Calculating the End Date */
          futercampaign.end_date = new Date(tempDate.setDate(tempDate.getDate() + searchparam.periodicity));
        })
      } else {
        resolve(() => {
          futercampaign.start_date = new Date(periodicity.setMonth(periodicity.getMonth() + num));

          /* Storing the start_date temporarily */
          tempDate = new Date(futercampaign.start_date);

          /* Calculating the End Date */
          futercampaign.end_date = new Date(tempDate.getFullYear(), tempDate.getMonth() + month, 0);
        })
      }
      /* Calculating the Deadline */
      futercampaign.deadline = new Date(tempDate.setDate(tempDate.getDate() - searchparam.deadline));

      return futercampaign;

    });

  }
```

and is been use it for this other method.

```
      public generateCampaigns(campaing: any, searchparam: any, ev: any): void {

        for (let i: number = 0; i < searchparam.number_campaigns; i++) {
          if (validapps[i]) {
            let copy: any = angular.copy(campaign);
            this.DatesGenerator(copy, searchparam, i).then(()=>{
            if (!searchparam.wildcard) {
              copy.application = validapps[i];
              copy.os = validapps[i].os[0];
              copy.version_app = copy.os.version[0];
              copy.campaing_code = validapps[i].application_code;
            }
            this.suggescampaigns.push(copy);
            });
          }
        }
      }
```

but when i call the second function give the error the tempDate is undefined and i dont know why, can somebody please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is exactly what is telling you, the tempDate is undefined because when you are using it isn't yet resolved in this line:

```
futercampaign.deadline = new Date(tempDate.setDate(tempDate.getDate() - searchparam.deadline));
```

You should use it when resolved. This means setting `futercampaign.deadline` inside the *resolves* of the *DatesGenerator* and returning *futercampaign* as the resolution of the promise.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the code embedded in the calls to resolve does not get executed until after your function exits, but you are accessing the uninitialized tempDate variable at the end of the function, before anything initializes it. The code you have inside the `this.$q()` method will be called at "some later time", which could very likely be after your second function exits.

It's not clear to me why you are using a promise for this since the code is synchronous. Promises are typically used for code that may be asynchronous. You should just remove all the promise wrapping and you will probably have what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes i think you are right i shouldn´t been using promises in that part, thanks so much for the advice.